# updating relative path of jar while working on different OS

Tags: ant

I would like to replace path of an existing jar based on OS .
Right now i am maintaning a text file called "build.start.properties" with all libraries some ting like this
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-servlet.jar
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-user.jar
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-dev.jar
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-soyc-vis.jar 
/log4j/X/1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar
/GWT_LOG/X/3.0.3/gwt-log-3.0.3.jar
/GWT_MATH/X/2.1/gwt-math-2.1.jar
/GWT_MATH/X/2.1/gwt-math-server-2.1.jar 
/GWT_Commons_Logging/X/0.3/GWT-commons-logging/gwt-commons-logging-0.3.jar
/GWT_Commons_Logging/X/0.3/GWT-commons-logging/gwt-commons-logging-service-0.3.jar

And loading them to classptah using below target

```
    <loadfile property="jars.list.property" srcfile="mybuild/build.start.properties">
        <filterchain>
            <expandproperties />
            <striplinecomments>
                <comment value="#" />
            </striplinecomments>
            <tokenfilter>
                <ignoreblank />
            </tokenfilter>
            <prefixlines prefix="," />
            <striplinebreaks />
        </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <filelist id="build.libs" dir="" files="${jars.list.property}" />

    <pathconvert targetos="unix" property="build_unix.libs" refid="build.libs">

        <map from="C:" to="${unix.xenv}" />
        <map from="" to="${unix.xenv}" />
    </pathconvert>
    <pathconvert targetos="windows" property="build_windows.libs" refid="build.libs">
        <map from="C:" to="${windows.xenv}" />
        <map from="" to="${windows.xenv}" />
    </pathconvert>
    <path id="build.classpath.id">
        <pathelement path="${build_windows.libs}" />
        <pathelement path="${build_unix.libs}" />
    </path>
    <echo message="Build Libraries classpath: ${toString:build.classpath.id}" />
</target>
```

from the above target build.classpath.id looks like 
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-servlet.jar:/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-user.jar:/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-dev.jar:/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-soyc-vis.jar:/log4j/X/1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/GWT_LOG/X/3.0.3/gwt-log-3.0.3.jar:GWT_MATH/X/2.1/gwt-math-2.1.jar:/GWT_MATH/X/2.1/gwt-math-server-2.1.jar:/GWT_Commons_Logging/X/0.3/GWT-commons-logging/gwt-commons-logging-0.3.jar:/GWT_Commons_Logging/X/0.3/GWT-commons-logging/gwt-commons-logging-service-0.3.jar

When i work on unix I have to pic only jar names from file "build.start.properties" and update path like this

/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-servlet.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-user.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-dev.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-soyc-vis.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-log-3.0.3.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-math-2.1.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-math-server-2.1.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-commons-logging-0.3.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-commons-logging-service-0.3.jar

Answer (score 0):

Use the conditions

```
<condition property="isWindows">
<os family="windows" />
</condition>
<condition property="isUnix">
    <os family="unix" />
</condition>

On the targets then u can use

<target name="path_if_unix" if="isUnix">
    <map from="C:" to="${unix.xenv}" />
    <map from="" to="${unix.xenv}" />
</target>
```

Comment: This is not going to work for me since on UNix relative path may change based on user.

Comment: U need to reformulate your question then ... since u want to know not only the OS , but also the user

Comment: How do u know which user do u want?